# GPathResult to org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, httpbuilder

This might be a very simple, but I'll ask anyway.

I have the following code that does a post to a web service. I am using HttpBuilder to build the request and post the payload. The method returns a GPathResult that I need to change into a org.w3c.dom.Node

I am using the Node for xpath evaluation, and need the result to be a org.w3c.dom.Node.

```
def responseXml
def onResponseHandler = { resp, content ->
            def soapResponse = content instanceof java.io.InputStreamReader ? content.getText() : content
            responseXml = soapResponse.Body
        }

http.post(body: payload, headers: ['Content-Type:': 'text/xml'], onResponseHandler)

return responseXml
```

I've searched quite extensively for this, but couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Ended up with a horrible, but working solution. Took the string of xml and used the documentbuilderfactory and parsed the string. Got myself a document and can do some xpath queries.

Comment: Curious, why did you have to use XPath notation and not GPath notation for this?

Comment: Well, actually because I had predefined xpath queries loaded from a database, using different queries for different types of documents and tests that also was predefined. All delightfully complicated, but very powerful way to test.